# Java - Execute Update MySQLSyntaxError

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, mariadb

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
Statement stt = connection.createStatement();
stt.executeUpdate("Insert into Tipp(Ergebnis,Spiel_IDFK,Benutzer_IDFK) 
Values('"+ ((TextField) node).getText() + "','" + node.getId() + "', 1')");
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 1

I couldn't really figure out what the problem with my syntax is, I would appreciate some help.

Comment: The extra ‘ at the end?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Do not use string concatenation to insert user-supplied text into a SQL statement. Use a `PreparedStatement` with `?` parameter markers. Unless of course you really want your code to be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, allowing hackers to steal your data and delete your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies at the end of the query, value `1` is missing quotes to its left.

```
"', 1')"
---^ '1'
```

Comment: Or rather it has excessive quote on the right. It is an ID column, so likely a integer datatype, which means it shouldn't have quotes.